# Do I need a comma after the "or"s?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, commas, clauses, oxford-comma

It shall not be published in any document or broadcasted or transmitted in any way.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. First, the past tense is *broadcast*, you don't need the *...ed*.

If you use a comma you don't need the first *or*. I would change the second *or* to *nor*, and place a comma in front of it.

So I would write the sentence:

***It shall not be published in any document, broadcast, nor transmitted in any way.***